# Set the top position fixed with the Angular spinner

Tags: html, css, angularjs, spinner

**HTML**

```
<div class="margin-top-10">
      <span us-spinner="{left: '91.6%',top:'74.2%',length: 5,width: 2,radius:4}" spinner-key="spinner-1"></span>
      <button class="btn btn-green" ng-click="">Send</button>
    </div>
```

[image]

I have used [angular spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) as shown above.It's working fine.But my question is how can I set the spinner always move with the button (Send).At this moment when I add some content over the page where I have to adjust the `top` property of the spinner every time.So could you tell me how to avoid this and set it on top of the button all the time ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make the parent `div` of the spinner to have a `position:relative` Then it's position is based on that parent div

Comment: @brenjt `margin-top-10` div ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the parent div of the spinner to have a position:relative Then it's position is based on that parent div

```
<div class="margin-top-10" style="position:relative;">
    <span us-spinner="{left: '91.6%',top:'74.2%',length: 5,width: 2,radius:4}" spinner-key="spinner-1"></span>
    <button class="btn btn-green" ng-click="">Send</button>
</div>
```

Or you could even try placing the us-spinner inside of the `<button>`

```
<div class="margin-top-10">
    <button class="btn btn-green" style="position:relative;" ng-click="">
        <span us-spinner="{left: '91.6%',top:'74.2%',length: 5,width: 2,radius:4}" spinner-key="spinner-1"></span>
        Send
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: 2nd solution is not working.But `style="position:relative;"` is working fine.Thanks a lot :)